# Add File Path in NODE JS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, path

What do we need to edit in the following code to add in our path?

Our path is app/public.  We want to be able to have all of the files in our public folder to be the main .html files.  I'm new to this, any help would appreciated!
Thanks so much!

```
var http = require("http"),
url = require("url"),
path = require("path"),
fs = require("fs")
port = process.argv[2] || 8888;

http.createServer(function(request, response) {

var uri = url.parse(request.url).pathname
, filename = path.join(process.cwd(), uri);

path.exists(filename, function(exists) {
if(!exists) {
  response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("404 Not Found\n");
  response.end();
  return;
}

if (fs.statSync(filename).isDirectory()) filename += '/index.html';

fs.readFile(filename, "binary", function(err, file) {
  if(err) {        
    response.writeHead(500, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write(err + "\n");
    response.end();
    return;
  }

  response.writeHead(200);
  response.write(file, "binary");
  response.end();
});
});
}).listen(parseInt(port, 10));

 console.log("Static file server running at\n  => http://localhost:" + port + "/\nCTRL + C to shutdown");
```

Comment: Why the -1 on my answer?

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you try and use `express`, to make it easier to handle, especially in the future as your app gets bigger.

```
var express = require( 'express' );
var app = express( );
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'); // might be useful. Not required though

app.set( 'port' , process.argv[2] || 8888 );
app.use( express.static( './public' ) ).use( cookieParser( ) ); // sets path to your public folder

// you can add some more configuration here

// then finally start your server
http.createServer( app ).listen( 
    app.get( 'port' ) ,
    function( ) {
        console.log( 'Express server listening on http port ' + app
                .get( 'port' ) );
        // here, complete with your callback
    } 
);
```

Here's the Express documentation : http://expressjs.com/